# Laravel 5.1 with gettext gives undefined function _() in console commands

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, php-gettext

I'm using Laravel 5.1 on Homestead. I translate strings with the Xinax/Gettext package (https://github.com/xinax/laravel-gettext). It all works perfectly except for when trying to run a console command containing translatable strings, for example `_('Test string')`.

The error I get is:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
Call to undefined function App\Console\Commands\_()
```

Any ideas on how to get the gettext functionality to work in the console environment?